# Does Improving Earth Conductivity Near a Buried Ground Rod Improve Antenna System Performance?

Tags: vertical-antenna, grounding, efficiency

The suggestion has been made on various ham-related websites that improving the conductivity of the Earth around a ground rod produces a worthwhile improvement in the e-m radiation from a vertical monopole using that ground rod. How effective **is** that?

Comment: Isn't "improving the conductivity of the Earth around a ground rod" the same thing as "installing radials"? Is there any question that radials are effective?

Comment: I edited my answer to deal with your observation.

Comment: How about lowering the earth resistance using Epsom salt (magnesium sulfate) around the rods? See *Signal Corps manual MIL-HDBK-419A* starting on page 2-59 "2-9 ELECTRODE ENHANCEMENT". Scroll down to the sketch used in many ARRL publications. Sorry I didn't have a link, you'll have too Google it. **ALSO**, [please see my own experience using Epsom salt](https://web.archive.org/web/20181115070846/http://www.w0btu.com/Beverage_antennas.html#Beverage_antenna_grounds).

Comment: A quick look at MIL-HDBK-419A prompts some concerns about its usefulness w.r.t. buried rods used as "r-f grounds."  The measured data it shows appears to apply to the relatively low-frequency a-c of the utility power distribution grid and lightning protection, while omitting the additional need to provide a low-R path to the Earth for transmit/receive antenna systems operating in their part of the e-m spectrum.

Answer (score 3):

Below for some perspective on this topic is a NEC4.2 analysis showing the difference in performance of a 40m, 1/4-wavelength, unloaded, base-fed vertical monopole antenna system when driven against either a 5/8" OD or a 12" OD, copper-clad, 8-ft long ground rod buried in poor Earth (1 mS/m, d.c. 5).

Increasing the ground rod OD up to 12" is the equivalent of modifying the Earth in that radius area around a 5/8" OD ground rod to be nearly a perfect conductor of the radial r-f currents in the Earth around the monopole, that flow toward the ground rod.

An improvement in system performance results, but not a very ***significant*** improvement.

[*Added October 7, 2020*]:
Improving the conductivity of Earth for several meters around ground rods buried at the base of a vertical monopole (or anywhere else) does almost nothing toward improving the conductivity of the ground plane out to a 1/2WL radius of the base of a vertical monopole.

Regardless of the height of that monopole in physical, free-space wavelengths, minimizing the ESR of the entire ground plane within 1/2WL radius around its base is critical to the radiation efficiency of that antenna system. That ESR is a series circuital element with a large affect on the relative amount of r-f current from the source (transmitter) that will flow along the monopole itself.

RF energy dissipated in the ESR of a set of radials buried in soil is converted to heat, rather than to useful e-m energy radiated into space.

Reference: **Ground Systems as a Factor in Antenna Efficiency**, Brown, Lewis & Epstein (RCA Labs); Proceedings of the I.R.E., 1937.

[image]

Comment: The graphic should say an 0.625" (5/8") ground rod rather than 0.0625", right?

Comment: That is right.  Thank you for catching my mistake. A corrected NEC graphic now is included in my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

If by improving conductivity, you mean flooding several acres or square miles with ocean (or saltier) sea water (or via natural intrusion near a low lying shoreline or wetlands), or installing a solid copper floor several square wavelengths in size in the parking lot, yes.

But some people have reported improved antenna performance by putting a metal mesh of gopher wire (not too deep) under their lawn, with the vertical antenna grounded in the middle.  Probably soldering or crimping adjacent mesh sheets is desirable.

Comment: RE: "If by improving conductivity, you mean flooding several acres or square miles with ocean (or saltier) sea water ..., yes." —  My answer addressed and concerned the conductivity of the region of the Earth within a 6" radius of the vertical axis of an 8-ft-long buried ground rod, however.

Comment: Wouldn't an only 6" radius in non-conductive ground be not much different from just having a larger diameter ground rod (12" iron pipe, etc.)?